# Using linq to count substrings in a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I could use the following linq expression to count the number of occurrences of a word as follows:

```
string test = "And And And";
int j = test.Split(' ').Count(x => x.Contains("And"));
```

However what if I was searching for "And And", Is there a way to use linq to count words without using split. Do any of these methods take longer the O(n)?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile...  Do you mean `int j = test.Split(' ').Count(x => x == "And");`?

Comment: Where is the linq expression in your code?

Comment: @Peri the Count extension method is the linq portion of the given expression.

Comment: Im not sure this is LINQ. LINQ is 'from x select something' and that is translated to Extension methods calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
string test = "And And And";
int j = Regex.Matches(test, "And").Cast<Match>().Count();
```

BTW, do you want to allow overlapping occurrences? i.e. if you're looking for "And And", do you consider that `test` contains 1 or 2 occurrences of it?

Comment: @Peri, it's because `MatchCollection` implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<Match>`, and `Count` only works on the generic version.

Comment: Don't forget to escape special regex characters if the string that you're looking for could contain them.

Comment: @Thomas: Don't know why but I was sure Matches returns an array of Match.

Comment: Never though of the case of two occurrences, but I guess it would be.

Comment: +1 for explaining the need for the `Cast`. Thanks @ThomasLevesque

Answer (score 1):

I found a clever solution that can be resolved serverside with most LINQ to ORMs:

```
string search = "foo";
int searchLength = search.Length;

var result = qry.Select(i => new { Object = i, Occurrences = (i.SomeProperty.Length - i.SomeProperty.Replace(search, "").Length) / searchLength });
```

The idea is to replace the substring by an empty string and then divide the difference in string length by the length of the search term.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx):

```
string what = "And";
int count = 0;
int pos = -what.Length;
for (;;)
{
    pos = input.IndexOf(what, pos + what.Length);
    if (pos == -1) break;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not using LINQ. OP is looking for a LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite Linq, but you can also make an extension method like below. It is probably more efficient than any Linq solution:

```
        public static int CountSubStrings(this string input, string delimiter, bool ignoreCase = false)
    {
        int instancesNo = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        while((pos = input.IndexOf(delimiter, pos, ignoreCase ? StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase : StringComparison.InvariantCulture)) != -1)
        {
            pos += delimiter.Length;
            instancesNo++;
        }
        return instancesNo;
    }
```