# LINQ2SQL - How to detect mutiple instances of one string within another

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to determine a way to find all words in a database table called 'Word' that contain certain letters which is easy enough for single instances of letters, for example if I want to find all words that contain 'L' and 'I' I would use:

```
Words.Where(w => w.Word_value.IndexOf("I") > 0 && w.Word_value.IndexOf("L") > 0)
```

However, if I needed to find all words containing the letter 'I' and three instances of the letter 'L' (e.g. 'LILLY'), I am at a loss.  Is there a way I can do a count of instances of a string within another?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: duplicate my friend. i am not marking it for closing anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144169/using-linq-to-count-substrings-in-a-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
int count = Words.Length - Words.Replace("L", "").Length;
```

Comment: I hope you checked why i stick to this method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using SQL Server's [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) capabilities.

Create a stored procedure that implements the functionality you require using full text search and then expose that using Linq to Sql or Linq to Entities.

Also see the [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) predicate.